# How do you make an array of blank, 8 by 8 sprite sheets in Paint.NET?

Tags: paint.net, image-sprite

Ok. This will be hard to explain. Basically, I have made an 8 by 8 sprite sheet in preparation for a Java 2D RPG I'm making. I made this in Paint.NET. Here is what it looks like:
[image]

You see, I'm not new to Java, but I am to game programming, so I'm following Ryan van Zeben (DesignsByZephyr)'s tutorials on making a Java 2D RPG. In the second episode of his series he appears to take a sheet quite like mine and convert it into an array of many sheets. So, he makes a grid that has other grids on it.

If you're still unsure what I mean then check out the video on YouTube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7pfq0W3e4I&list=TLCpbhtBxFFX5rEXsyeN0nyXGDCOg5kyxY&index=3. Skip to 4:18 or thereabouts. Then, once he has talked he does something with "blending options" and in turn creates what I'm talking about.

Now, I don't have access to Photoshop so I can't repeat the same process. However, I do want to do what he was doing in Paint.NET. I am a very big noob when it comes to Paint.NET, so I would have no idea how to do this. I was wondering if you could help me.

So to sum all that up my final question is this:

***How do I recreate what DesignsByZephyr was doing in Episode two of his making a Java 2D RPG series at roughly 4:45 in Paint.NET?***

Thank you so much for reading this. I want the final product to look something like this:
[image]

Yeah. Once again, thank you. Any support or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually a grid.
I don't think you can do this easily "out of the box" in paint.net, but you may find a plugin that allow this.

Here is one of them: http://paint.net.amihotornot.com.au/Features/Effects/Plugins/Render/Grid_CheckerBoard_Maker/

To answer your question using this:

- Install the grid/checkboard plugin
- Select in foreground and background colors the two colors of your grid (light pink and dark pink in your case)
- Open the Grid/Checkboard plugin dialog (see image below)
- Select horizontal and vertical steps of 8 pixels
- Select Mode: "Grid lines"
- Select Drawing position: "Top left"
- Click OK

[image: Grid/Checkboard plugin's dialog]

Comment: Just found your other topic with the same question... Please try not to ask the same thing twice as it's a loss of time for you and the peoples trying to help you; If you can use both Gimp and paint.net, I'd recommend Gimp. It's a little harder to use, but once you get it, it's a lot more powerful (especially if you know a little python or lisp).

Comment: You will actually find that the first question was aiming at how to create the first image in this question. This question was aimed on how to multiply the first image in this question. You are right about GIMP, however :)

Comment: My bad. I was mislead by the title of the question (a "sprite sheet" usually contains more than one sprite).

Comment: That's fine... I'll admit that I'm extremely bad with sprites, so my terminology could be a bit shabby when it comes to that kind of stuff.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I have one question. It works fine, I'm just not quite sure how to set the two colours I want (dark pink for the outline and light pink for the "content"). I think you referred to these in your answer as the background and foreground colours. Correct me if I'm wrong. So yeah, do I have to set them manually or is there a way to do that in the grid setup? Thank you for your help once again.